# How do I check the state of a NSURLSessionDownloadTask in the completion handler block?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Say I create an `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`:

```
let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: { location, response, error in
    ...
}
```

If I call `cancel()` on that downloadTask later, it will still call the completion handler, right? I want to check if the state of the download task is `Cancelling` so it won't try to mess with the downloaded image there wouldn't be one in this case.

I can't check the state of the download task itself as it's within the creation of the variable.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `error` parameter in completion handler. Or check `NSURLSessionTask`'s `state` property. If it is equal to 'NSURLSessionTaskState.Completed' then download task is not cancelled. Documentation says:

> The task has completed (without being canceled), and the task's
>   delegate receives no further callbacks. If the task completed
>   successfully, the task’s error property is nil. Otherwise, it provides
>   an error object that tells what went wrong. A task in this state is
>   not subject to timeouts.

Comment: I can't check the state of the task as it's within the task's initialization.

Comment: You are correct. Swift does not allow that. You can use delegation instead of block based completion. In the `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` method you can check the `downloadTask`'s `state`

Answer (score 0):

The completion handler will only get executed when the task completes and so you can actually use it on instantiation. Why not leverage a capture list to force a weak cycle:

```
let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: [weak downloadTask] { location, response, error in
    ...
}
```

Bear in mind that the tasks state will likely be `completed` inside the handler so what you should be checking is the error parameter